# How do I change a char's values?

Tags: c++

I've created a program and it runs, however there are two problems. 1) Char doesn't change values as it should. 2) One of my total variables is stuck on one.

I've tested the code multiple times, and the char deptID is stuck on 'B'. I've tried going through the workflow and it's stuck on the value. Just to make sure, I wrote a cout line to check it throughout the workflow. Regardless of what I input, it's stuck on 'B'.

2) The variable TechTotal is seemingly stuck on 1. I've tested it using different values as well. I also went ahead and used a cout line to determine the value throughout the workflow to no success. I've made sure the variables are correct in calculating the variable. Both are correct.

Here's my main code:

````
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    welcomeScreen();
    long int empID;
    int TechAccAvg, TechTixAvg;
    int BusTotal, TechTotal, BusAccAvg, BusTixAvg;
    char deptID;
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "What department are you apart of?\n";
        cin >> deptID;
        if (deptID = 'B')
        {
            auto Averages = gatherData(deptID);
            BusTixAvg = std::get<0>(Averages);
            BusAccAvg = std::get<1>(Averages);
            cout << BusTixAvg << endl; 
            cout << BusAccAvg << endl; 
            BusTotal = BusTixAvg + BusAccAvg;
            cout << "Bus Total: " << BusTotal << endl;
        }
        else if (deptID = 'T')
        {
            auto TechAverages = gatherData(deptID);
            TechTixAvg = std::get<0>(TechAverages);
            TechAccAvg = std::get<1>(TechAverages);
            cout << TechTixAvg << endl;
            cout << TechAccAvg << endl;
            TechTotal = TechTixAvg + TechAccAvg;
            cout << "Tech Total: " << TechTotal << endl;
        }
    }
      cout << "Tech: " << TechTotal << endl;
      cout << "Business: " << BusTotal << endl;
      summaryReport(TechTotal, BusTotal);
      goodByeScreen();
      return 0;
     }```



`   std::tuple<int, int> gatherData (char dept)
    {
    tuple <double, double> Averages;
    int employeeNum=0, TotalTix=0, TotalAcc=0, trafficTickets=0, accidents=0;
    long int empID=0;
    double TixAverage=0, AccAverage=0;
    char deptID;
    cout << dept << endl;
    cout << "How many employees do you have?\n";
    cin >> employeeNum;
    for(int j = 0; j < employeeNum; j++)
    {
    cout << "Please enter your employees ID number\n";
    cin >> empID;
    cout << "How many tickets did they have this year?\n";
    cin >> trafficTickets;
    TotalTix += trafficTickets;
    cout << "How many accidents did they have this year?\n";
    cin >> accidents;
    TotalAcc += accidents;
    }
    TixAverage = TotalTix / employeeNum;
    AccAverage = TotalAcc / employeeNum;
    cout << "Department: " << dept << endl;
    cout << "Total employees: " << employeeNum << endl;
    cout << "Total tickets: " << TotalTix << endl;
    cout << "Total Accidents: " << TotalAcc << endl;
    Averages = make_tuple (TotalTix, TotalAcc);
    return Averages;
}```

This is used to create the tuple that is used in determining Totals for both 'B' and 'T' depts. 

Fixing both the char dept and the TechTotal would fix the entire program, I think. Those are the only things holding the program back. I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and I'm kind of lost as to why it's not changing those values. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Replace `else if (deptID = 'T')` with `else if (deptID == 'T')` and `if (deptID = 'B')` with `if (deptID == 'B')`.

### Explanation

The single equal sign `=` means assignment. Therefore, everytime the program runs, `deptID` will be assigned to `B` and the statement will return `true`, satisfying the `if` statement.

However, you want to compare two values to see if they are equal. Therefore, you must use `==` (equality).

Because the statements in the `else if` will never execute, `TechTotal` will remain uninitialised, and the value in that memory address just so happens to be `1`.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you immensely. That was a really dumb mistake on my part, but thank you so much for answering and getting straight to the point! Fixed my problem.